# Silverstripe 3 - Extend Init() with DataExtension

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to overwrite the init() function in my Page_controller. I have a DataExtension to extend the controller. With a function found here http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataextension#object-extension-injection-points

But beforeExtending seems not to exist

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PageControllerExtension::beforeExtending()
```

That's my function in the extension to achive this

```
function __construct() {
        $self = $this;

       $this->beforeExtending('init', function() use ($self) {
          $themeFolder = $this->ThemeDir();
            $tweaks = 'tweaks';

            $CSSFiles = array(
                $themeFolder . '/css/layout.css'
        );

            $JSFiles = array(
             $tweaks . '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
             $tweaks . '/js/jquery.unveil.js',
             $tweaks . '/js/jquery.bxslider.js',
             $tweaks . '/js/wow.js',
                $themeFolder . '/js/load.js'
            );

            Requirements::set_combined_files_folder($themeFolder . '/combined');
            Requirements::combine_files('screen.css', $CSSFiles);
            Requirements::combine_files('screen.js', $JSFiles);
       });

       parent::__construct();
    }
```

where's the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend Extension rather than DataExtension if you are not extending a data object.

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but you could try $this->owner->beforeExtending

Comment: no also not. but I found out it's just 'onBeforeInit()' but it stops working if you enter the /Security page

Comment: That's because Security is a separate controller with a fake "Page", so the onBeforeInit method isn't applied to it.